# Heap size in C++ Cygwin

Tags: c++, memory, g++, cygwin, heap-memory

I need to allocate a lot of memory and I am fine with Cygwin use all my RAM. My installed RAM is 12GB. I have problem running the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    // arma::mat::fixed<10,10000> buffer; // ok
    arma::mat::fixed<10,100000> buffer; // cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile
    // arma::mat::fixed<10,100000000> buffer; // cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile
    std::cout<<"Allocation was successful."<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I receive a run-time error:

> 0 [unknown (0x1F40)] a 7656 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.stackdump

Which shows there is no enough memory. By reducing the allocated size the error disappears.

I use

```
regtool -i set /HKLM/Software/Cygnus\ Solutions/Cygwin/heap_chunk_in_mb 2048
g++ main.cpp -larmadillo
a.exe
```

But it seems `regtool` here cannot fix the problem while suggested in some websites.

Comment: Don't use fixed size matrices (`arma::mat::fixed<rows,cols>`) with large dimensions. This just eats up memory from the limited stack. Instead, use the standard matrix (`arma::mat`). For example: `mat buffer(10,100000,fill::zeros);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arma::mat::fixed actually allocates the memory on the stack, which size is quite limited. It hunk that you should use the arma::mat constructor but I'm not sure because I never worked with arma.

Comment: May I please ask you which tool you have used to detect it uses stack not heap?

Comment: I've looked here: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat it says that it allocates the memory at compile time, this seems to be a stack allocation.